# How do I convert a specific controller to a package to include in other projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

VS2013, MVC5, VB

I am nearing the completion of a small project to manage the roles tables in a standard MVC5 application.  The code is pretty much encapsulated.  What are my options for using this 'package' in other projects?

Can I compile it into something?  I know this type of action is possible, I'm just not familiar with the options available to me or the steps to do this.  Links to sites that have tutorials are fine.  Is creating a Nu Get package the only way to go, or is that even in the ballpark of what I'm asking.  I say Nu Get, but I don't mean for public consumption, only for my consumption.

Will the finished 'whatever' include it's controller class, view models and views?  Will I be able to easily manage updates?  etc.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Nuget package is one way. I have created a local repository of common utilities for this purpose. But I usually use it just for DLLs. I use [Nuget Package Explorer](https://docs.nuget.org/create/using-a-gui-to-build-packages) for its ease of use since its just me using the packages most of the time. Not sure its possible to place the files in specific directories.

> Files in the content folder are copied to the root of your application when the package is installed. - [Nuget](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package)

The alternative is to create an item template. I used to use this method for class files I want in my code but I can't see why you couldn't do it for the rest. Works well and isn't too hard to set up. There are dozens if not 100s of tutorials on the subject. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365680/Extending-Visual-Studio-Part-Item-Templates) is one on code project.